# Show two nonzero vectors $v$ and $w$ have the property $v\otimes w=w\otimes v$ iff there is $\lambda$ such that $v=\lambda w$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, tensor-products, universal-property, free-modules

I am struggling with the following problem.

> Let $V$ be a $F$-free module on a finite set over a field $F$. Prove
>   that in $V\otimes_F V$ two nonzero vectors $v$ and $w$ have the
>   property $v\otimes w=w\otimes v$ if and only if there is $\lambda$
>   such that $v=\lambda w$.

I have the converse argument to be the following:

---

($\Leftarrow)$ Let $v$ and $w$ be two nonzero vectors. Suppose there exists $\lambda$ such that $v=\lambda w$. We want to show that $v\otimes w=w\otimes v$. Consider \begin{eqnarray*}
v\otimes w &=& \lambda w \otimes w \text{ because $v=\lambda w$}\\
&=& w \otimes \lambda w \text{ by a relation of the tensor product}\\
&=& w\otimes v\text{ because $v=\lambda w$}
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus $v\otimes w=w\otimes v$ as desired.

---

I feel good about my proof of the converse. The forward direction is giving me trouble however. Here is my attempt:

---

($\Rightarrow)$ Let $v$ and $w$ are two nonzero vectors. Suppose we have the property $v\otimes w=w\otimes v$. We want to show that there exists a $\lambda$ such that $v=\lambda w$. Notice $V$ has a finite basis, call it $B$. By definition of a free module, for every nonzero $v,w\in V$ there exist unique nonzero $r_i,s_i\in F$ and unique $b_i\in B$ where $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that
$$
v=\sum_{i=1}^n r_ib_i\hspace{3mm}\text{ and }\hspace{3mm} w=\sum_{i=1}^n s_ib_i
$$
Because $B$ is finite, we have $V=Fb_1\oplus \cdots \oplus Fb_n\cong F^n$.

---

This is where I get struck. I thought about trying to apply the universal property of a tensor product, but I am not sure how to go about this exactly.

**Questions:**

(1) Is a good approach to prove $(\Rightarrow)$ or is there a better way?

(2) Is what I have done so far correct?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Revision after help below:**

Let $v$ and $w$ are two nonzero vectors.  We will prove this problem using the contrapositive. Suppose $v\neq \lambda w$. This means $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent. We want to show $v\otimes w\neq w\otimes v$.

Notice $V$ has a finite basis, call it $B$. By definition of a free module, for every nonzero $v,w\in V$ there exist unique nonzero $r_i,s_i\in F$ and unique $b_i\in B$ where $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that
$$
v=\sum_{i=1}^n r_ib_i\hspace{3mm}\text{ and }\hspace{3mm} w=\sum_{i=1}^n s_ib_i
$$
Because $B$ is finite, we have $V=Fb_1\oplus \cdots \oplus Fb_n\cong F^n$ (pg. 354). By corollary 19 (pg. 374), we have $V\otimes_F V$ to be a free $F$-module of rank $n^2$ with basis $b_i\otimes b_j$ such that $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
F^n \otimes_F F^n\cong F^{n^2}=F^n\times F^n.
\end{eqnarray}
Claim $\{v,w\}$ is contained in some basis of $V$. Clearly $v,w$ are linearly independent by our assumption. Additionally $v,w\in\text{span}(B)$ by the definition of $V$ as a $F$-free module. Therefore we have $v$ and $w$ are in some basis of $V$. This means $v\otimes w$ and $w\otimes v$ are in some basis of $V\otimes_F V$. Then $v\otimes w=v\times w$ and $w\otimes v=w\times v$. Notice $v\times w= w\times v$ only if $v=w$, which is false because they are linearly independent.  Thus $v\otimes w\neq w\otimes v$, proving the contrapositive.

Hence if $v\otimes w=w\otimes v$, then $v=\lambda w$ for some $\lambda\in F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the forward direction, suppose $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent and find a basis of $V$ containing $\{v,w\}$. The corresponding basis of $V \otimes V$ contains $v \otimes w$ and $w \otimes v$. In particular, $v \otimes w \not = w \otimes v$.

Your proof of the converse direction is good.

Comment: Ok. So for contradiction, suppose $v\neq \lambda w$. This means $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent. Therefore for $\alpha,\beta\in F$
$$
\alpha v + \beta w =0 \hspace{3mm}\Leftrightarrow \hspace{3mm} \alpha=\beta=0.
$$ Right?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand what you want to say by this.

Comment: Yeah. I wondered if I would need that.... I didn't see how that help. I was just recalling a fact I knew about linear independence. I am trying to figure out how to go about finding the basis. My gut is $\{v,w\}$ but I am pretty sure that is wrong.

Comment: In my answer, I'm using a basic result for tensor products of vector spaces: if $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a basis of $V$, then $\{v_i \otimes v_j\}$ is a basis of $V\otimes V$.

Comment: Ok. I don't know why, but this is not clicking for me. I am brand new to working with tensor products. Here is what I am thinking....The basis in my case is $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$. Then $\{b_i\otimes b_j\}$ is a basis of $V\otimes V$. Notice \begin{eqnarray*}
b_i\otimes b_j&=&b_i\otimes b_j\cdot 1 \\
&=& b_i\cdot b_j\otimes 1\\
&=& b_i\cdot b_j(1\otimes 1)
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $1\otimes 1$ is a basis of $V\otimes V$. Notice 
$$
v(1\otimes 1)=v\otimes 1
$$
and
$$
w(1\otimes 1)=w\otimes 1
$$
Then $\{v,w\}$ must be in the basis of $V$. Is this right? I'm skeptical.

Comment: No, not at all. I don't know what you mean by $1 \otimes 1$; it is certainly not a basis of $V \otimes V$. Are you well brushed up on your linear algebra? What book are you reading?

Comment: I'm reading Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote.

Comment: Ok. So I reviewed some of my linear algebra. I will be honest it has been awhile. Clearly $v,w\in \text{span}(B)$ because of what I knew about a free-module, and since we assume $v,w$ to be linearly independent, we have $v,w\in B$. Therefore we have $v\otimes w$ and $w\otimes v$ in the basis of $V\otimes V$. Because $v$ and $w$ are unique elements, we have  $v\otimes w \neq w\otimes v$.

Comment: Yes, $v$ and $w$ are in *a* basis of $V$, not necessarily the basis you started with. I don't understand what you mean by "unique elements". See corollary 19, page 374, of Dummit and Foote, for some pointers.

Comment: I tried revising my question above using your hints. Please let me know if you still here errors. Sincerely thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way with the universal property that needs not you trust that $e_i \otimes e_j$ form a basis. (As Olivier showed, if you trust that, then the statement is trivial since it is just focuses on the independence of *a particular pair* ${e_i \otimes e_j, e_j \otimes e_i}$ out of the entire set whose independence you already trust.)
I'll try to explain my personal *thought process* which lead me to this result because I'm still a beginner in category language and I hope it'd be helpful to others, too.

#### Thought process

In loose terms,  the mapping $\otimes : V\times V\to V\otimes V$ is (the) most *general* bilinear mapping out of $V\times V$ in the sense that it

1. "forgets" no information from $V\times V$, and
2. adds no more than necessary.

These two are captured by the universal property which makes sure any other bilinear function out of $V\times V$ is 1. **recoverable** from $\otimes$ (no data loss!) in 2. a **unique** way (no excess data!).

With $u\otimes v=v\otimes u$ (or, $\otimes(u,v)=\otimes(v,u)$ to stress that $\otimes$ is a map out of $V\times V$), we kind of lose the information that **$(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$ were different** before being processed by $\otimes$. It seems $\otimes$ violates point 1. of the universallity.

How can we show this? Point 1. is about recovability of bilinear functions out of $V\times V$, so we can hope to find a bilinear map which cannot be constructed by composition with $\otimes$.

And this is where I was stuck for a few days because I didn't know how to construct bilinear functions until I found the answer in the body of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2227003): for a fixed basis $\{v_i\}$ of V, a bilinear map $B:V\times V\to W$ is determined uniquely by (linear extension of) the equations $B(v_i,v_j)=w_{ij}$ for any choices of $w_{ij}\in W$. In this simple case it suffices to use the underlying field for $W$.

#### Answer

1. Construct a bilinear map $B:V\times V\to F$ that **tells the difference** between $u$ and $v$ with $B(u,v)=1$ and $B(v,u)=0$. This is possible if $u,v$ are independent because 1) they can be completed to a basis and 2) a bilinear map can be determined on a basis this way.
2. Apply the universal property of $\otimes$ for $B$: since $\otimes$ is universal, then $B$ should be recoverable from it by some linear $h:V\otimes V\to F$: $$B=h\circ\otimes.$$
3. Evaluate this equation on both $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$: $$1=B(u,v)=(h\circ\otimes)(u,v)=h(u\otimes v)\\0=B(v,u)=(h\circ\otimes)(v,u)=h(v\otimes u).$$ Obviously, if $u\otimes v=v\otimes u$, we'd get $1=0$, i.e. the independence of $u,v$ is inconsistent with the $u\otimes v=v\otimes u$.

#### Moral

If $\otimes$ forgot the difference between $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$, then we wouldn't be able to reconstruct from it any other bilinear function which *does* tell the difference. Since $\otimes$ is universal, that's impossible, i.e. such bilinear functions shouldn't exists. But that can only happen if $u,v$ are linearly dependent.

For me, that last piece was missing - how these mappings are constructed. Always know your maps!