# When is $x \otimes y = y \otimes x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $X$ be a vector space and $x \otimes y \in X \otimes  X$.
 Under which conditions is $x \otimes y  = y \otimes x$? Does it  nessecarily follow that $x = \lambda y$ for some $\lambda$ in the underlying field?

Comment: Given that $X$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space, the tensor product $x \otimes y$ of the vectors $x, y$ in $X$ is the matrix whose $j$th column is the column vector $(x_i y_j),$ where $x_i$ and $y_j$ are the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ with respect to some basis.

Comment: For a simple example, consider the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R^2$ with vectors $x = (1, 2)$ and $y = (1, 1).$ We have that $x \otimes y = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Another possible duplicate is this question where I just posted my findings: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187095/show-two-nonzero-vectors-v-and-w-have-the-property-v-otimes-w-w-otimes-v-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not entirely correct (consider $y=0, x\neq0$). But yes, $x\otimes y=y\otimes x$ means that $x$ and $y$ are collinear / linearly dependent.

Comment: I see, how can one prove this? This should be a simple algebraic manipulation but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Chose some suitable linear forms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and evaluate $\alpha\otimes \beta$ on $x\otimes y$